# Extracting certain integers from string C++

Tags: c++, string, int

Good day to all,

I am having a hard time trying to extract desired integers from a string. I am given the following to read in from a file:

itemnameitemnumber price percentmarkup

examples

- Gowns-u2285 24.22 37%
- TwoB1Ask1-m1275 90.4 1%

What I have been trying to do is get the item number separated from the item name so that I can store the item number as a reference for sorting. As you can see the first example itemnameitemnumber is a clear cut character to digit separation, whereas the next example has numbers within its item name.

I have tried several different approaches, however with certain item names having integers apart of their name is proving to be beyond my experience.

If anyone can help me with this I would be greatly appreciative for their time and knowledge.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Otherwise, you are asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: "I am having a hard time" gives readers nothing to work with. Please post what you tried and identify where it fails.

Comment: *I have tried several different approaches* - You mean like getting the first item, and searching backwards starting from the right until a non-digit is found?  If you did that, then you don't get into the problem of digits being intermingled with non-digits.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

I don't know, if you have a fixed number of digits for `itemnumber`, but i am going to assume that you don't.

This is a simple approach; first you have to separate the words of your line. For example, use `std::istringstream`.

When you have the line split to words, for example by giving its iterators to a vector, or reading it with `operator>>`, you start to check the first word from backwards, until you find *anything* that is **not** one of `"0123456789 "` *(note the whitespace at the end)*.
After you've done this, you get the iterator about where these digits end (from backwards), and cut your original string, or if you have the opportunity, the already split string. Voilá! You have yourself your item name and item number.

For the record, i am going to do this whole thing, utilising the same technique for the percent markup too, of course with the exception characters being `"% "`.

```cpp
#define VALID_DIGITS "0123456789 "
#define VALID_PERCENTAGE "% "

struct ItemData {
    std::string Name;
    int Count;
    double Price;
    double PercentMarkup;
};

int ExtractItemData(std::string Line, ItemData & Output) {
    std::istringstream Stream( Line );

    std::vector<std::string> Words( Stream.begin(), Stream.end() );

    if (Words.size() < 3) {
        /* somebody gave us a malformed line with less than needed words */
        return -1;
    }

    // Search from backwards, until you do not find anything that is not digits (0-9) or a whitespace
    std::size_t StartOfDigits = Words[0].find_last_not_of( VALID_DIGITS );

    if (StartOfDigits == std::string::npos) {
        /* error; your item name is invalid */
        return -2;
    }
    else {
        // Separate the string into 2 parts
        Output.Name = Words[0].substr(0, StartOfDigits); // Get the first part
        Output.Count = std::stoi( Words[0].substr(StartOfDigits, Words[0].length() - StartOfDigits) );
        Output.Price = std::stod( Words[1] );

        // Search from backwards, until we do not find anything that is not '%' or ' '
        std::size_t StartOfPercent = Words[2].find_last_not_of(VALID_PERCENTAGE);
        Output.PercentMarkup = std::stod( Words[2].substr(0, StartOfPercent) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Code requies includes `sstream`, `vector`, `string`, and `cstdint` if you do not have size_t defined*

Hope the answer was useful.
Best of luck, COlda.

PS.: My first answer on stack overflow ^^;

Answer (score -1):

you can iterate on the string pushing the numbers to a vector then use stringstream to convert them to integers